# Is hiding the YouTube player when a video stops playing violates the YouTube API terms of service?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, youtube, youtube-api

In my Flash/AIR application, the YouTube player is not shown when no requested video is being played so as to leave more space (which is limited) to my application's content. The user is also given an option to disable the YouTube feature altogether and just focus on my app's content.

Nothing in my app is interfering with the overlayed YouTube ads while a video is being played. But when a video finishes or the user stops a video, a larger overlayed YouTube ad appears just before the player gets hidden. From my experience with the API, the final ad does not appear in all cases, only in some.

In this connection, I'm worried whether or not this behavior somehow infringes the [YouTube API terms of service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms). I'm primarily concerned with paragraph 7 in the Prohibitions section:

> Your API Client will not, and You will not encourage or create functionality for Your users or other third parties to ...  7. modify, replace, interfere with or block advertisements placed by YouTube in the YouTube Data, YouTube audiovisual content, or the YouTube player;

Is hiding the YouTube player qualifies as "blocking" the ads?

Comment: yes, you block it, because it is not visible.

Comment: @csomakk Does it mean that, once the YouTube player appears in the app, I have no power to hide or remove it because it can be showing an ad at any arbitrary moment?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Terms of Service / legal issues instead of directly about programming.